# How to cover reactive form control optional chaining in Jasmin test cases

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-reactive-forms

```
submit() { 
let name = this.form.get('name')?.value
}
```

how to cover the  `?.` operator ?

I tried setting form values `null` :

```
 it('makes expected calls: show unsaved message', () => {
     
      const formData = {
        name: null,
        description: null,
      };
      component.form.setValue(formData);
      component.onSubmit();
    });
```

Comment: You might want to give it a try and than ask a more specific question about the part you would have difficult with. SO provides us with a good guide as to [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with a better chance to get the help you are after.

It is also a good idea to provide a minimum reproducible problem in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)